# How can I get hover to work over a border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation for my portfolio and I can't get rid of that weird jump when I hover from one link to another. I know it's because of the bottom-border but i need that for design reasons.

I've been trying to find a solution forever and I can't find it anywhere. I've also tried outline instead of border bottom and ::after, and I've tried javascript/jquery.

```css
.navi--link:link,
.navi--link:visited {
  font-size: 7.2rem;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d6d6d6, #5BC0EB);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden; }

.navi {
  position: relative; }

.navi__center {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  transition: all 2s;
  display: block; }

.topDiv .navi--link {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  display: block; }

.topDiv {
  height: 2.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6; }

.topDiv:hover,
.topDiv:active {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
      <nav class="navi clearfix">
            <ul class="navi__center">
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="topDiv">
                    <li><a class="navi--link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I'm not getting any errors I'm just getting a weird jump when I move from one link to another, and I know it's from the border.

Comment: It seems to be working fine when I press the "Run code snippet" but in my browser it bounces when I get to the border.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: The latest version of chrome